# AngularJS + Firebase ng-show doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ng-show

I'm not expert with angularjs and firebase, but I made this short code and I cann't solve why doesn't work.

I need to test if user is logged in (with firebase authentication) and if user is logged in I want to show 'div' element. If user is not logged in 'div' shoud be hidden.

My html code looks this way:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="memberonly" ng-show="loggedIn">
      <h1>This is visible only for logged in user.</h1>
  </div>
<body>
```

And script is here:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    console.log('user logged in.');
    $scope.email = user.email;
    console.log($scope.email);
    $scope.loggedIn = true;
    console.log('$scope.loggedIn: ', $scope.loggedIn);
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    console.log('no user logged in.');
    $scope.loggedIn = false;
    console.log('$scope.loggedIn: ', $scope.loggedIn);
  }
});
});
</script>
```

In console I can see correct values but still ng-show doesn't works.
I see if user is logged in, I see his email, loggedIn is set to 'true'.
Could anyone help?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Do you have a `$scope` variable called `loggedIn` somewhere else in your app ? try to change the name of your `loggedIn` variable to see if it works.

Comment: No, this is only place where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope.$apply()` after giving value to `$scope.loggedIn`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    console.log('user logged in.');
    $scope.email = user.email;
    console.log($scope.email);
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.loggedIn = true;
    })
    console.log('$scope.loggedIn: ', $scope.loggedIn);
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    console.log('no user logged in.');
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.loggedIn = false;
    })
    console.log('$scope.loggedIn: ', $scope.loggedIn);
  }
```

Comment: Yes, this will probably work too, problem solved :-)
Thank you.